# Assign same value to ties in ranking

Tags: r, ranking

I have some data that looks like this:

```
Value <- c(-0.07, -0.07, -0.0003, 0.45, 0.45, 1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4)
```

I need to convert it to "ranked" data but I would like all ties to be given the same value AND the rankings to be sequential, such that:

```
# new.value
1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5
```

I've tried the `rank()` function in R but I'm having trouble with the ties.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn the ranks into a factor, and then convert the factor into integers.  Consider:

```
rank(Value)
# [1] 1.5 1.5 3.0 4.5 4.5 6.0 8.0 8.0 8.0
as.numeric(factor(rank(Value)))
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In `dplyr`, you can simply use `dense_rank`:

```r
dplyr::dense_rank(Value)
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5 5 5
```